# Mask image or video with inline SVG

Tags: css, svg, bootstrap-4

I'm making a simple tool for converting images and videos from one aspect ratio to another selected one.
My first attempt was to use the same img tag twice:
1st: opacity 0.5
2nd: I calculated and applied a clip-path. (That way the user can see the whole image, and which rectangle is going to be around after cropping.)

Apart from bad practice way of loading the same image twice, I'll also need to do this for video. 
Having the same video twice will make things really overloaded and I'd really like to avoid that (apart from the whole problem of making sure both are playing the same frame, pause/play at the same instant etc.).

I've read up a little about SVG, how you can use them. SVG seems the right tool to use. I only need to support the latest browser versions so I don't need IE 8 support.

To complicate things more, the images bootstrap 4 responsive, and the images and videos have different aspect ratios (and might be rotated) so fixed width/height on the SVG won't work.

For example, I have an image.
It has an aspect ratio of 4:1.
The user wants to convert it to 1:1.
I then calculate that the crop-factor is inset(0% 33.33%) (2/3 needs to go, and I want it centered).
For this example the SVG needs to be 100% of the image. White everywhere except one black rect on the left side and one on the right side both having 33% height and 100% width.
(See snippet below if the text makes no sense)

I've never really used SVGs so I'm a bit confused. I need it to be inline as I need to alter the width and height of the 4 squares with javascript and my attempts have not got anywhere so far.

An example showing it with an SVG using the image once and masking using 4 squares (2 being 0 width/height and two being 33.33%/100%) for this exact example is very much enough, I'll be able to add the JS controlling the sizes of the squares.

This is the essence / way of how I'm going about it now:

```css
.overlay-image {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -3px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col mx-auto" >
  <div class="row h-100" style="background: #ff0000;">
    <div class="row h-100"style="background: #00ff00;">
       <div class="mx-auto my-auto col-6"style="background: #0000ff;">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/UNICEF_Logo.png" class="img-responsive fit-image img-fluid overlay-image">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/UNICEF_Logo.png" class="img-responsive fit-image img-fluid " style="clip-path: inset(0% 33.33%);">
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**
This is a step in the direction I'm looking for. Doing the masking I'm faking above with two images instead with a SVG. I realise the image I selected to show isn't that great, just picked a reasonably small one with CC license.

What I'm looking for in an answer based on the below snippet:

- Make the image fill the width of the containing div and have the
  required height to not break the image aspect ratio, and scaling the SVG to contain it's content.
- Using bootstrap centre the image horizontally and vertically
- Any thoughts in the image width and height attributes, if it's something I should set to 100 100 and by having the first point fixed not having to think about it, or if it's something (along with the mask rect) I need to adjust depending on the image size and aspect ratio

Hope this makes my question clearer.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="col mx-auto" >
  <div class="row" style="background: #ff0000;">
    <div class="row "style="background: #00ff00;">
       <div class="mx-auto my-auto col-6"style="background: #0000ff;">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"  style="outline: 1px solid red" class="  ">  
          <defs>  
            <mask id="image-mask" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50">  
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" fill="#00F0FF" />
              <rect x="33" y="0" width="33" height="50" fill="white" />
            </mask>  
          </defs>
          <image width="100" height="50" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class=" "  xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/57/UNICEF_Logo.png" mask="url(#image-mask)" />  
        </svg>

      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you really want as an ultimate output ? do you want to create text shadow?

Comment: The same as my snippet (well, it's a bit shifted with the two images but the geist). So the center 1/3 of the image fully visible and the left and right 1/3 half transparent. To show that the centre 1/3 is what will be left

Comment: svg directly offers `<image>` tag, and you can use the same CSS

Comment: I thought you could use the 'use' tag for the image and possibly video, with the image tag wrapped around a 'g' tag with extra attributes and the use tag with other attrs. But still can't quite understand what you require.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to phrase it better, I basically know nothing about the capabilities of SVG+CSS (and making it work in both FF and Chrome). I'd like to replace the first image with opacity for an SVG mask. So the way I envision it it would take 4 rectangles in that SVG, one for masking from each direction. In this case the top and bottom would have width:100% and height0% while the left and right would both have height:100% and width 33%. Or if that's easier to control a rectangle in the centre showing the image and then having height 100% and width 33% with the centre in the centre of it

Comment: I suggest that yo do as much of this  in CSS. Then finally if CSS doesn't work try svg. The raster image might need to still be in an svg wrapper. Your question is very strongly based around responsive design. With CSS, is CSS Grid Layout one way you could solve your challenge?   Take a look at [CSS Grid Layout by Rachel Andrew](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/) who is highly respected with CSS.